# Unable to capture the checked , unchecked status of the checkbox in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox control in my angular 7 application and need to capture checked  unchecked value as and when the checkbox is selected or deselected.

```
<td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[44]" class="tableItem">
    <label style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
        <input type="checkbox" #myId  (checked)="isHurdleRateSelected(s)" value="{{f.HurdleRate}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> Yes
    </label>
</td>
```

#### Component

```
isHurdleRateSelected(s) {
  this.isHurdle = s;
}
```

At the moment, I tried using the checked and change event. When using change event, the value that is being captured in the code behind shows undefined while checked property doesnt seem to hit the break point.

Could somebody tell me how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" #myId  (checked)="isHurdleRateSelected($event)" value="{{f.HurdleRate}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> Yes
```

in the new `isHurdleRateSelected($event)`:

now if you in .ts print the value:

```
isHurdleRateSelected(event) {
console.log(event);
     //   this.isHurdle = s;
    }
```

After it prints you can read a lot of values and you can find checked attribute.